# Refining GUI developed by RGTK2

Tags: r, gtk2

I am developing a GUI using R and GTK2 and created something as shown in the photo.

Here's the script:

```
library(RGtk2)

rm(list=ls())

window.master <- gtkWindow("toplevel",show=FALSE)
window.master$setDefaultSize(1024,768)
window.master$set(title="Window Name")

forms.notebook <- gtkNotebook()
forms.notebook$setTabPos("top")

form1.notebook <- gtkNotebook()
form1.notebook$setTabPos("top")

form1.boxp1.y3 <- gtkVBox(FALSE,3)

form1.framep1y1 <- gtkFrame("AAA")
form1.boxp1y1.2y <- gtkVBox(FALSE,2)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.4x <- gtkHBox(FALSE,4)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.4x$packStart(gtkLabel("BBB"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.4x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.4x$packStart(gtkLabel("CCC"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.4x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x <- gtkHBox(FALSE,4)
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x$packStart(gtkLabel("DDD"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x$packStart(gtkLabel("EEE"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)
form1.boxp1y1.2y$add(form1.boxp1y1.y1.4x)
form1.boxp1y1.2y$add(form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x)
form1.framep1y1$add(form1.boxp1y1.2y)

form1.framep1y2 <- gtkFrame("FFF")
form1.boxp1y2.2y <- gtkVBox(FALSE,2)
### 1nd row ###
form1.boxp1y1.y1.6x <- gtkHBox(FALSE,6)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.6x$packStart(gtkLabel("GGG"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.6x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.6x$packStart(gtkLabel("HHH"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.6x$packStart(gtkEntry(),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.6x$packStart(gtkLabel("III"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y1.6x$packStart(gtkEntry(),FALSE,FALSE)
### 2nd row ###
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x <- gtkHBox(FALSE,4)
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x$packStart(gtkLabel("JJJ"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x$packStart(gtkLabel("KKK"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)
### 3nd row ###
form1.boxp1y1.y3.4x <- gtkHBox(FALSE,4)
form1.boxp1y1.y3.4x$packStart(gtkLabel("LLL"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y3.4x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)
form1.boxp1y1.y3.4x$packStart(gtkLabel("MMM"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y1.y3.4x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)

form1.boxp1y2.2y$add(form1.boxp1y1.y1.6x)
form1.boxp1y2.2y$add(form1.boxp1y1.y2.4x)
form1.boxp1y2.2y$add(form1.boxp1y1.y3.4x)
form1.framep1y2$add(form1.boxp1y2.2y)

form1.framep1y3 <- gtkFrame("NNN")
form1.boxp1y3.2y <- gtkVBox(FALSE,2)
### 1nd row ###
form1.boxp1y3.y1.6x <- gtkHBox(FALSE,6)
form1.boxp1y3.y1.6x$packStart(gtkLabel("OOO"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y3.y1.6x$packStart(gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE)
form1.boxp1y3.y1.6x$packStart(gtkLabel("PPP"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y3.y1.6x$packStart(gtkEntry(),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y3.y1.6x$packStart(gtkLabel("QQQ"),FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1y3.y1.6x$packStart(gtkEntry(),FALSE,FALSE)
### 2nd row ###
form1.boxp1y3.y2.2x <- gtkHBox(FALSE,2)
form1.boxp1y3.y2.2x$packStart(gtkCheckButton("RRR"),TRUE,TRUE)
form1.boxp1y3.y2.2x$packStart(gtkCheckButton("SSS"),TRUE,TRUE)

form1.boxp1y3.2y$add(form1.boxp1y3.y1.6x)
form1.boxp1y3.2y$add(form1.boxp1y3.y2.2x)
form1.framep1y3$add(form1.boxp1y3.2y)


form1.boxp1.y3$packStart(form1.framep1y1,FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1.y3$packStart(form1.framep1y2,FALSE,FALSE)
form1.boxp1.y3$packStart(form1.framep1y3,FALSE,FALSE)


form1.boxp2.ud <- gtkVBox(FALSE,2)
form1.framep2f1 <- gtkFrame("TTT")
form1.framep2f2 <- gtkFrame("UUU")
form1.boxp2.ud$add(form1.framep2f1)
form1.boxp2.ud$add(form1.framep2f2)

form1.boxp3.ud <- gtkVBox(FALSE,1)
form1.framep3f1 <- gtkFrame("VVV")
form1.boxp3.ud$add(form1.framep3f1)

form1.boxp4.ud <- gtkVBox(FALSE,1)
form1.framep4f1 <- gtkFrame("WWW")
form1.boxp4.ud$add(form1.framep4f1)

form1.boxp5.ud <- gtkVBox(FALSE,1)
form1.framep5f1 <- gtkFrame("XXX")
form1.boxp5.ud$add(form1.framep5f1)


form1.notebook$add(form1.boxp1.y3)
form1.notebook$add(form1.boxp2.ud)
form1.notebook$add(form1.boxp3.ud)
form1.notebook$add(form1.boxp4.ud)
form1.notebook$add(form1.boxp5.ud)
forms.notebook$add(form1.notebook)
window.master$add(forms.notebook)

window.master$show()
```

I have a few questions:

1. How to change the tab name? (I can't use Page1,Page2,Page3 everywhere)
2. How to add spacer between each row/frame?
3. I want to display information from the dataframe into the `gtkEntry` field, I think I need to give label of the `gtkEntry` field, how can I do that?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few answers:

- **How to change the tab name? (I can't use Page1,Page2,Page3 everywhere):**

  Instead of `form1.notebook$add(form1.boxp1.y3)` use `form1$appendPage()` with the `tab.label` option. See `?gtkNotebookAppendPage`
- **How to add spacer between each row/frame?**

  For a layout like this you should be using `gtkTable`. For `gtkVBox` you can use `setSpacing` (`?gtkBoxSetSpacing` and/or `padding` when packing.
- **I want to display information from the dataframe into the gtkEntry field, I think I need to give label of the gtkEntry field, how can I do that?**

Not sure what you want to do here. I'm guessing you want to a) name your `gtkEntry` objects and then set their text. If you coordinate your names with your data frame this can be done quickly. For example, using a list to store the entries along the lines of (from your  BBB label):

```
 l <- list()
 form1.boxp1y1.y1.4x$packStart(l$BBB <- gtkEntry(),TRUE,TRUE) ## BBB from your label
```

etc.

Then supposing your data frame has a column BBB (along with others) you can do something like

```
sapply(names(l), function(i) l[[i]]$setText(your_dataframe[1,i]))
```

Or if you don't like so many ['s you could use:

```
mapply(gtkEntrySetText(l, your_dataframe[1, names(l)])
```